# Joining MS teams meeting with two devices and sharing screen from one device

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have two devices: an Ipad and a Mac. I am using the MS teams app on both. I can join meetings with both devices at the same time using the same account.

Up until recently I could share the screen of the Ipad (e.g. to draw something) and see the screen content of the Ipad on my Mac. While it is still possible now to share the screen of my Ipad with other participants, my own Mac is no longer showing my shared Ipad screen.

Conversely, when I share my Mac screen, I can see it on my Ipad.

What could possibly cause this? Any help getting my Ipad screen showing up on my Mac again is appreciated. Thanks!

I have crossposted this on the MS community
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/joining-ms-teams-meeting-with-two-devices-and-sharing-screen/m-p/1399773#M58795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works if I log in with different accounts on the two devices. On my main computer, I am using my professional account. On my phone, I am using my private account. Then, if I invite my phone from my main computer, I can join with my phone as if it were a regular attendee to the meeting. In particular, this allows me to see the camera from my phone on my main screen.

Alternatively, you can just open a web browser on your main machine and log in on the web browser via a guest account. This will also allow you to see exactly the same that any attendee of your meeting sees.